# UseStore is async? How to ensure that store-data is loaded completely?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, zustand

I have a serious problem with State Management in React. I am using Zustand and it works pretty well.

However, when I access the store and try to output it one the console, for example:

```
const USER = useStore(state => state.currentUser) 
console.log(USER)
```

the result logged is null. If the page rerenders it is the correct userobject.

The store is set up as follows:

```
import react from "react";
import create from "zustand";

const useStore = create(set => ({

    currentUser: null
}))

export default useStore
```

Thus, I suppose that useStore works asynchronously, i.e. updates the variable with the pages next render. Is that correct?
So, how can I ensure that the store variables are loaded completely, before I continue?

Hope, the problem is clear to everyone?

Thanks in advance,

Wiwi

Comment: You're probably setting the user in store async, long after `useStore(state => state.currentUser)` runs, so the first time your code runs, it will be null, because it's not set yet. If you edit the question with how you set the user in the store, it will probably show the issue.

Comment: You don't show where you set the user, I'd suggest [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to guide how to edit your question to get answers faster. Either way, you're likely asking how to handle async data setting in react, there's lots of resources and questions for this.

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and then edit your question post, also, your answer isn't an actual answer, it got downvoted because of it. by deleting this your reputation would be back.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by [Andy Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743464/andy-ray) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144294/usestore-is-async-how-to-ensure-that-store-data-is-loaded-completely/72145447#comment127470696_72144294):

> You're probably setting the user in store async, long after `useStore(state => state.currentUser)` runs, so the first time your code runs, it will be null, because it's not set yet. If you edit the question with how you set the user in the store, it will probably show the issue.

I used an async Func for the user data - that solved the riddle for me!

Answer (score 0):

In some such case where the persistent storage works asynchronously, there is a trick that a developer use to understand when the load got finished.

After rehydration a callback function should be added to set the loading state and then the developer can catch it up and use it for his/her purpose.

The following codes will be only an example:

```js
import { create } from 'zustand';
import immer from 'immer';
import { createJSONStorage, persist } from 'zustand/middleware';
import dataKeys from '../dataKeys';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { isFunction } from 'lodash';
import type { ProfileDataType } from '@types';

type UseProfileStateStoreType = {
  isLoaded: boolean;
  setLoaded: (flag: boolean) => void;
  picked?: ProfileDataType;
  setPicked: (userData?: ProfileDataType) => void;
  clear: () => void;
};

export const useProfileStateStore = create<UseProfileStateStoreType>(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      isLoaded: false,
      setLoaded: (flag) => {
        set(
          immer((state) => {
            state.isLoaded = flag;
          })
        );
      },
      picked: undefined,
      setPicked: (p?: ProfileDataType) => {
        set(
          immer((state) => {
            state.picked = p;
          })
        );
      },
      clear: () => {
        set(
          immer((state) => {
            state.isLoaded = false;
            state.picked = undefined;
          })
        );
      },
    }),
    {
      name: dataKeys.profile,
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => AsyncStorage),
      onRehydrateStorage: () => (state) => {
        if (isFunction(state?.setLoaded)) {
          state?.setLoaded(true);
        }
      },
    }
  )
);
```

As you see, the above code is for `React Native` and it tries to manage the state of profiles, when the app got opened, and Zustand finished the rehydration an `isLoaded` flag would be `true` and the developer can understand the store is ready to use.